# Can an ADF-test distinguish between stationarity and trend stationarity?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am learning Time series analysis and I am studying the augmented Dickey Fuller test. My understanding of the null hypotheses is clashing with all the explanations I find online and in books. I refer to the notation of the picture attached.

For a series I am working on all $\tau$- and $\phi$-nulls are rejected, for all three options "none", "drift" and "trend" in R. Many places online I see if $\phi_2$ is rejected they conclude "trend stationarity" even tho $\tau_{\tau}$ also rejects. But if $ \gamma \neq 0$  as tested in all the $\tau$-Nulls, my thought is that all the other hypotheses will be rejected as well.

My understanding of the Null $\phi_2$ is that $a_0=0$ AND $a_2=0$ AND $\gamma=0$. And if just 1 of them is different from 0 the Null hypothesis is rejected. Hence if $\tau_1$ is rejected all the other Nulls will also be rejected. So I can't see how I can conclude anything more than "No unit root" if the $\tau$ is rejected.

The only case where I see I can conlude a trend is if a unit root is present AND a time trend present. Because then all $\tau$ would fail to reject, but $\phi_2$ would reject.

What do I miss here?

So the main questions:

How do I conclude trend stationarity if there is no unit root?

How do the results of the 3 different ADF-tests relate to each other?

[image: **Overview of which model is tested and the null hypothesis for the Augmented Dickey fuller test. **]